# primefaces p:schedule didn't show up at first time

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using a p:schedule but it won't show up at the first time I entered the page

I have to refresh the page once and then it comes out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:form id="form">
    <h:outputScript library="js" name="primefaces-locale-zh.js" />
        <div class="top-extra-title">
            <h:outputText value="#{menu.miMeetingScheduleView}" />
        </div>
            <p:schedule id="schedule" value="#{meetingScheduleView.meetingSchedule}"
                widgetVar="meetingSchedule" timeZone="GMT+8" draggable="false"
                locale="zh" >
                <p:ajax partialSubmit="true" event="eventSelect" listener="#{meetingScheduleView.onEventSelect}"
                    update="mform :content" />
            </p:schedule>
    </h:form>
</ui:composition>
```

```
@ManagedBean(name = "meetingScheduleView")
@ViewScoped
public class MeetingScheduleView implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    SessionUser sessionUser;
    private String accountOrgId;

    private static final String msgFile = "cyberstar.module.meeting.meeting";

    private List<Meeting> meetingList;

    private ScheduleModel meetingSchedule;
    private ScheduleEvent event;

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{sysAdminPage}")
    private SysAdminPage sysAdminPage;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        sessionUser = JSFUtil.getSessionUser();
        if(sessionUser==null){
            MsgUtil.showErrorMsg(msgFile, "infSessionUserFail", "infSessionUserFailDetail");
            sessionUser.logoff();
        }
        accountOrgId = sessionUser.getOperator().getOrgId();

        meetingList = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
        meetingSchedule = new DefaultScheduleModel();
        event = new DefaultScheduleEvent();

        initialize();
    }

    public void sendMeetingUnid(){
        ExternalContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        String issueUnid = context.getRequestParameterMap().get("meetingUnid");
        LinkedHashMap<String , String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<String , String>();
        if (sessionUser.getSendDataMap().get("meetingView") == null) {
            hm.put("meetingUnid", issueUnid);
            sessionUser.getSendDataMap().put("meetingView", hm);
        } else {
            hm = sessionUser.getSendDataMap().get("meetingView");
            hm.put("meetingUnid", issueUnid);
        }
    }

    public void initialize(){
        try {
            if (sessionUser.isCyberStar()) {
                meetingList = MeetingDAO.getAllMeeting();
            } else {
                meetingList = MeetingDAO.getMeetingByOrgId(accountOrgId);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < meetingList.size(); i++) {
                Meeting m = meetingList.get(i);
                if (m.getStatus().equals(MeetingStatus.sketch)) {
                    continue;
                }
                DefaultScheduleEvent dsEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(m.getTitle(), m.getStartTime(), m.getEndTime(),m.getUnid());
                if(m.getStatus().equals(MeetingStatus.cancel)){
                    dsEvent.setStyleClass("redEvent");
                }
                meetingSchedule.addEvent(dsEvent);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            MsgUtil.showErrorMsg(msgFile, "infUpdateFail",
                    "infUpdateFailSQLExceptionDetail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onEventSelect(SelectEvent selectEvent) {
        event = (ScheduleEvent) selectEvent.getObject();
        String issueUnid = String.valueOf(event.getData());
        LinkedHashMap<String , String> hm = new LinkedHashMap<String , String>();
        if (sessionUser.getSendDataMap().get("meetingView") == null) {
            hm.put("meetingUnid", issueUnid);
            sessionUser.getSendDataMap().put("meetingView", hm);
        } else {
            hm = sessionUser.getSendDataMap().get("meetingView");
            hm.put("meetingUnid", issueUnid);
        }
        try {
            sysAdminPage.openView("meetingForm");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            MsgUtil.showErrorMsg(msgFile, "infUpdateFail", "infUpdateFailExceptionDetail");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

these are the codes of button which direct to the page

```
<p:menuitem value="#{menu.miMeetingScheduleView}" styleClass="meetingScheduleView"
                onclick="highlightme('meetingScheduleView')" action="#{sysAdminPage.menuSelected}"
                update="mform :content">
                <f:param name="viewname" value="meetingScheduleView" />
            </p:menuitem>
```

my goal is to show the p:schedule just when I enter the page

Comment: what does console of your browser show?

Comment: I think it's a ajax problem because if I set ajax="false" on the button which direct to the page,it do show up at the first time

Comment: can you post the code of the button that directs to this page

Comment: And at that situation when I refresh the page it will show a "Confirm Form Resubmission"(I translate it from chinese) dialog every time. And whatever the current page is, it will be redirected to the schedule page after I refresh it.

Comment: Now I write a method to refresh the page while entering the schedule,somehow it worked. but i think it's just a expedient solution